# How to limit the occurrence of a randomly generated item in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, random

Suppose, an array can hold 10 elements and I want it to fill it with random integers ranging from 1 to 5. In C++, it can be easily done by using rand().

But I want to limit the number of occurrences of the digit 5 to TWO times. [ At the end, the array must contain two 5s. ]

So, is there any function in C++ to set this constraint?

This is what I've done so far.

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{   num=rand()%5+1;
    if(num==5)
    {   if(count<2)
        {   count++;
            arr[i]=num;
        }
        else
        {   i--;
            continue;
        }
    }
    else
        arr[i]=num;
}
```

If you have any ideas, feel free to share it with me. Thanks.

Comment: Not with `rand`, you can't. Maybe if you created your own random function.

Comment: Ok. Any other way to obtain the result?

Comment: Is 5 the only number that's limited here?

Comment: Isn't this just a generator?

Comment: Yes. I took 5 as an example.

Comment: You do not want 5 after the second time. What keeps you from randomising only up to 4 from then on?

Comment: Randomness is pretty easy.  You list all the things that are equally likely and then select among them with uniform distribution.  The problem with your question is that you have not defined whether you intend for all possible outcomes to be equally likely.

Comment: I have edited the question. Is it possible to reopen my question guys?

Comment: `limit the number of occurrences of the digit 5 to a maximum of 2 times` and `At the end, the array must contain two 5s` are not the same thing. Do you want *at most two 5* or exactly *two 5* ?

Comment: The array must contain exactly two 5's at the end of execution.

Comment: If the array must contain exactly two 5s then there are only 8 random elements. So generate 8 elements, add in the 5s, and reshuffle.

Answer (score 1):

Just keep track of if you've already generated a 5, in a custom generator

```
class arunAJs_generator {
    int number_of_fives=0;
public:
    int operator()() {
        if (number_of_fives == 2) {
            //return random number 1-4
            return rand() % 4 + 1;
        } else {
            //return random number 1-5
            int value = rand() % 5 + 1;
            if (value == 5)
                ++number_of_fives;
            return value;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    arunAJs_generator gen;
    int values[10];
    std::fill(std::begin(values), std::end(values), gen);
}
```

Comment: Please don't encourage no-effort questions by answering them

Comment: I think 5 should be allowed twice, not just once, otherwise that's probably the best approach.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi: Discovering the idea of a generator can be tricky, as well as the syntax. This shows that, and little more.

Comment: @Pranav I have already done with my question. I was just checking out if there is a function in C++ or not.

Comment: @Mooing Duck That's a good idea. Changing the range of random. Thanks.